# How to format decimal in Swift to percentage

Tags: ios, swift, string, floating-point, double

I have a function which finds percentage difference of adjacent values in an array.

```
var values =  [1.623,1.614,1.591,1.577,1.600,1.579,1.622]
values.reverse()
let percentages = [0] + zip(values, values.dropFirst()).map { (old, new) in
    return (100.0 * (new - old) / old)
}
print(percentages)
```

> [0.0, -2.651048088779294, 1.3299556681444034, -1.4375000000000082, 0.8877615726062151, 1.445631678189826, 0.5576208178438598]

Is there a way i can format my values to look like the below

> ["+0.006%","+0.014%","+0.009%","-0.014%","+0.013%","-0.027%"]

Comment: Use a `NumberFormatter` with the `numberStyle` set to `.percent`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could start with a `NumberFormatter`, for example...

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .percent
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
formatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 1
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3

var values =  [1.623,1.614,1.591,1.577,1.600,1.579,1.622]
values.reverse()
let percentages = [0] + zip(values, values.dropFirst()).map {
    (old, new) in
    return (100.0 * (new - old) / old)
}

print(percentages.compactMap { formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: $0 / 100.0)) })
```

which will print something like....

```
["0%", "-2.651%", "1.33%", "-1.438%", "0.888%", "1.446%", "0.558%"]
```

> Your string only shows the signal for negative numbers. This is not what OP asked.

Heaven forbid the OP might actually have to do "some" work

```
print(percentages.map { ($0 >= 0 ? "+" : "") + formatter.string(for: $0 / 100.0)! })
```

Or, preferably...

```
formatter.positivePrefix = "+"
//....
print(percentages.compactMap { formatter.string(for: $0 / 100.0) })
```

which prints...

```
["+0%", "-2.651%", "+1.33%", "-1.438%", "+0.888%", "+1.446%", "+0.558%"]
```

> can you explain a little further if possible with example how the numbers can be fudged?

The format of the value doesn't seem to match the value your are producing, for example, `0.8877615726062151` would be `0.8%`, not `0.009%`, so you have a slight customisation, which would best accomplished by "fudging" the values slightly.

So, again, starting with...

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .percent
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
formatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 1
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 3
formatter.positivePrefix = "+"
```

I modified

```
print(percentages.compactMap { formatter.string(for: $0 / 100.0) })
```

to

```
print(percentages.compactMap { formatter.string(for: $0 / 10000.0) })
```

which now prints

```
["+0.000%", "-0.027%", "+0.013%", "-0.014%", "+0.009%", "+0.014%", "+0.006%"]
```

which based on my observations, seems to be what you're aiming for - you just get localisation for free

Comment: No need to convert your floating number to NSNumber. You can use `Formatter`s `string(for: Any)` method

Comment: @LeoDabus *"Your string only shows the signal for negative numbers."* - Yes, but it's a starting point, got to give the OP something to do ;). Maybe it's just me, but *"You can use Formatter string(for: Any) method"* hasn't worked for me in the past (might have changed recently, but my old code works this way)

Comment: I am pretty sure it works. Just change `from` to `for`

Comment: @LeoDabus It probably does, as I said, it didn't for me the past, so I just copy and pasted it ;)

Comment: Even thou this is close to the answer ,the core is to perfect  the values  down to `0.009` instead of  `0.888`.

Comment: @BigFire Then I would suggest you need to "fudge" your values a little more, pretty sure the formatter won't be able to do that for you

Comment: @BigFire You could also have a look at `.roundingMode` and `.roundingIncrement` of the `NumberFormatter`, but I think you're going to be fighting a lot more then just fudging your results, but that's me

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you explain a little further if possible with example how the numbers can be fudged?

Comment: @MadProgrammer i will mark  this as the accepted answer because it is highly detailed .Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just return string in map closure

```
let percentages = [0] + zip(values, values.dropFirst()).map {      (old, new) in     
    let value = (100.0 * (new - old) / old)  
    return String(format: "%.3f%%", value)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[0.0, -2.651048088779294, 1.3299556681444034, -1.4375000000000082, 0.8877615726062151, 1.445631678189826, 0.5576208178438598]
.map{String(format:"%+6.3f%%",$0/100)}
```

This one will provide the +/- signs.